# Symfony2: How to modify a form value before validation

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I have the following situation:

- a form field type `date`
- a validation pattern like `dd.mm.YYYY`
- a helper object that turns `12` into `12.07.2012` or `2.5` into `02.05.2012` etc.

**My question is: Where do I call the method that transforms the input value?**

When I call it from the `set`-method of the entity, the value actually gets changed. But when loading the form again (e.g. incomplete submit) the old value (like `2.5`) and not the transformed value (`2.5.2012`) is shown. Now, how do I tell the form, that the value has changed within the entity?

Maybe there's also another way of doing it in-between:

```
$form->bindRequest($request);
// do some fancy stuff here
if ($form->isValid()) {}
```

**PHP**

This is from the *Entity*:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
protected $date_start;
```

This is from the *Type*:

```
$builder->add('date_start', 'datetime', array(
    'label' => 'Start Datum/Uhrzeit',
    'date_widget' => 'single_text',
    'time_widget' => 'single_text',
    'date_format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
    'with_seconds' => false,
    'required' => false,
));
```

Comment: I posted an answer below but if you need more detail feel free to post the code for your form type and the model and I can probably get more specific.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways to modify forms and the data bound to them. You can use form events, there is an example of their use [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html) or you can use a DataTransformer which is explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

From the sound of your case I think a DataTransformer makes the most sense. You are representing the data in the object in one way but you need to present it in the form in a different way, and reverse that transform when the form is submitted. This is purpose of the DataTransformer.

Comment: Many thanks, the `DataTransformer` seems to be exactly, what I'm looking for.